# AS3 - How to make more than one of the same sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a 'Space Dodger' game in AS3, and all is going well, however, I find it too easy. The 'asteroids' only come in after the last one has hits the edge. I want the game to make more asteroids come towards you, but when I embed another image, it seems to throw me an error. The code is here:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author DogeGames Studios
     */


    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        var text:TextField = new TextField();
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var stext:TextField = new TextField();
        var sform:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var score:Number = 0;
        var stageRef:Stage
        public var inair:int = 1;
        [Embed(source = 'img/char.png')]
        var charClass:Class;
        var char:Bitmap = new charClass();
        [Embed(source = 'img/rock.png')]
        var rockClass:Class;
        var rock:Bitmap = new rockClass();
        public function Main():void 
        {

            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private var moveTimer:Timer;
        private var hitTimer:Timer;
        private var scoreTimer:Timer;

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            addChild(rock);
            addChild(rock);
            addChild(rock);
            scoreTimer = new Timer(1000, 0);
            scoreTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addScore);
            scoreTimer.start();
            hitTimer = new Timer(25, 0);
            hitTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, hitDetect);
            hitTimer.start();
            moveTimer = new Timer(25, 0);
            moveTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveRock);
            moveTimer.start();
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveShip);
            var watermark:TextField = new TextField();
            watermark.text = "DogeGames.cu.cc";
            var wform:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            wform.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
            wform.size = 24;
            wform.font = "Comic Sans MS";
            watermark.setTextFormat(wform);
            text.text = "Space Dodger - By Dogegames Studios ";
            char.x = 50;
            char.y = 482;
            rock.x = 850;
            rock.y = Math.random() * 600;
            format.size = 24;
            format.font = "Comic Sans MS";
            text.setTextFormat(format);
            text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            sform.font = "Comic Sans MS";
            sform.size = 24;
            sform.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
            addChild(text);
            addChild(char);
        }

        function moveShip(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (char.y >= 600) {
                char.y = 500;
            } else {
                char.y = mouseY;
            }
        }

        private var speed:Number = 15;

        function hitDetect(e:TimerEvent):void {
            if (char.getBounds(stage).intersects(rock.getBounds(stage))) {
                text.text = "GAME OVER!";
                text.setTextFormat(format);
                moveTimer.stop();
                hitTimer.stop();
                scoreTimer.stop();
            }
        }

        function addScore(e:TimerEvent):void {
            score++;
            stext.text = "Score: " + score;
            stext.setTextFormat(sform);
            stext.width = 700;
            addChild(stext);
        }

        function moveRock(e:TimerEvent):void {
            rock.x -= speed;
            if (rock.x <= 0) {
                rock.x = 850;
                rock.y = Math.random() * 600;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get? And are you refering to the 3 x `addChild(rock)`?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get another rock by adding the same one again. It will only be moved to the top of the display list. Plus, you need to track each instance of your rocks so you can do the collision detection on them later on.

instead of var rock:Bitmap = new rockClass(); use a vector, and initialize it in your constructor.

```
var rocks:Vector.<Bitmap>;
public function Main():void 
{
  rocks = new Vector.<Bitmap>();
  rocks.push(new RockClass());
  rocks.push(new RockClass());
  rocks.push(new RockClass());
  if (stage){
    init();
  }else{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
  }
}
```

add them with a loop, which will work fine as you change the number of rocks

```
//inside init()
for(var i:int=0; i< rocks.length; i++){
  addchild(rocks[i]);
}
```

The same kind of loop should be used for collision detection too.